# Safe way to store secretAccessKey on iOS application

Tags: ios, security, amazon-s3

I am using amazon S3 to provide IAP content.

Is there a "Safe" way to store the secretAccessKey inside my app so hackers can't use it to get the files?

Comment: Do you really need to store permanent credentials or would temporary credentials (eg valid for 1 hour) be good enough ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung This will be great, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is not to give out normal secret access keys at all.

First create an IAM user that has access to only what is needed, so that even if someone does get their hands on the credentials they can only access what you want them too (e.g. get files from a specific S3 bucket, but not modify them)

When the iOS app needs to access the S3 files it connects to a web server you control. That web server users [STS](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html?r=3044) to generate a set of credentials that will expire after the desired amount of time. These look like normal aws credentials (access key, secret, session id) but will eventually expire.

Amazon provide some reference implementations of these [token vending machines](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-tvm-identity) and has an [article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490) discussing the setup in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look for appropriate method using Keychain framework? [Keychain Services Tasks for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html)